# PodioComment::get_for( $ref_type, $ref_id ) ignoring attributes

Tags: podio

I'm collecting `Podio` item comments via `PHP` and recently realized that the comment count has surpassed 100, resulting in the most recent comments (#101 and above) not being returned. I cannot seem to get limit or offset to work as a mechanism for gathering the most recent comments. No matter what values I send I get 100 items returned (the default limit) beginning at `offset = 0`.

Is there anything incorrect with the below structure?

```
$comments=PodioComment::get_for( 'item', $item->id, array('limit' => 100, 'offset' => 50));
```

This incorrectly returns 100 comments, beginning at 0.

Thanks for any feedback...

Comment: Does changing the limit (without the offset) have any affect on your response? Have you tried changing your values to strings rather than integers?

Comment: Thanks for the response. For simplicity's sake I removed the offset and just tried to get the limit working. It doesn't work whether the limit is specified as an integer, or as a string like so: $comments=PodioComment::get_for( 'item', $item->id, array('limit' => '20'));

Comment: Thanks for humoring me.

I've copied/pasted your code into a dummy client and it's working as I'd expect it (for both the limit and the offset) using an item I have that has over a hundred comments.

I assume you're not getting an error and that you're looking at the results of the intended item/block. Would you be able to share more of your code?

Comment: You're correct. I'm not seeing any errors. I get 100 results and they are indeed associated with the intended item. I'll provide a few additional code snippets below. Thanks for your help! `$comments=PodioComment::get_for( 'item', '274932472', array('offset' => '20'));      var_dump($comments);` Looking at the var_dump I can immediately tell that 100 records have been returned (the default limit) and I see that the first item in the array is the first comment on the item, so the offset isn't working...`array(100) {
  [0] =>
  class PodioComment#3 (5) {
    public $__attributes =>`

Comment: Also, I should note, I get exactly the same result when using limit, like so... `$comments=PodioComment::get_for( 'item', '274932472', array('limit' => '20', 'offset' => '20'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an outdated version of podio-php-master. Updating to the latest stable release available on github resolved the issue.